# Testing admob before publish

Tags: android, admob

I have fishished an android project and set up admob ads but it's not working, tried on emulator and phone. So how to check if admob works?

Code:

```
    admobView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "Top secret");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    admobView.setLayoutParams(lp);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    layout.addView(renderView);
    layout.addView(admobView);
    admobView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    setContentView(layout);
```

The app works fine(renderView) but I have no idea if adView does. And yes, the admob ID is right.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can test AdMob in emulator also. You need the test mode to achieve that. See tutorial Step 6 for more info: [How to integrate Admob into your app](http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=724&recipeFrom=ViewTOC)

If you don't find the device ID in LogCat you can also try to add the TEST_EMULATOR constant:

```
request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
```

Comment: Thanks, looks great, but I dont have the AdManager class in some way despite I have the latest verson on the sdk.

Comment: The link provided on how to integrate AdMob into your app is outdated.  It was written before the Google AdMob rewrite of the SDK.  Please use `request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);` as mentioned above, or see http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/bestpractices.html#testmode for help on how to set test mode with the latest SDK version.

Answer (score 3):

All those links are obsolete, to test, replace your Banner ID for the one mentioned by Google here (section "Give your app an Ad Unit ID"):
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

And replace your Interstitial ID with the one mentioned by Google here (section "Instantiating the InterstitialAd object"):
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial