# AdMob android CTR drop after setting refresh rate

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have two questions about AdMob in Android:

**1)** I have started earning with AdMob in my apllication for some days, and my CTR was quite good. But yesterday I noticed that I was set "use refresh rate set in client code" but in my app I hadn't set any rafresh rate, so I have changed in AdMob settings Automatic Refresh on 60 seconds.
Yesterday I had many clicks and today I have very few, but impressions are even higher.

Maybe clicks update with delay compared to impressions?

**2)** Do I have to add package name to AdMob previously if I want to only test ads in my other apps which I am making?

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't think that there is any difference in the delay, you will just get some days with lots of clicks, and others with very few, that just depends on the luck of which ads are shown to the user. (5% is a very high click through rate)
2. For testing ads in new apps, I usually make a new site/app, but you can use test mode, like is described here - [Testing that admob working before publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991254/testing-that-admob-working-before-publish)

Comment: But don't you think that drop is connected with changing automatic refresh to 60 seconds? But at the beginning I didn't set any refresh rate nowhere and as I remember ads was refreshing every 60 seconds (maybe it's set by default).

Comment: No, I don't think so, but different types of apps have different users and so what I recommend that you should do is play around with the refresh rate until you find an optimum CTR