# Admob Integration for android issue?

Tags: android, admob

Hey Friends i am new in android,i have developed Application in android and integrates admob in android application but i got email from google like **invalid traffic,remove invalid activity** and then my admob account is disable.i was using admob with google play services. Please Help me and tell me any good tutorials for integration admob in android.

And i got this email from admob also

Violation explanation

GOOGLE PLAY REMOVAL: AdMob publishers are not permitted to abuse or promote the abuse of any Google product, such as Google Play, YouTube, or Blogger. This includes circumventing, or providing the means to circumvent, the policies or terms of these or other Google products, such as by allowing users to download YouTube videos.

If your app is removed by Google Play policy enforcement, please contact Google Play about an app removal here. If Google Play reinstates your app, please submit an appeal to our team.

Action required: Check account for compliance
While ad serving has been disabled to the above app, your AdMob account remains active. We suggest that you take the time to review the rest of your applications to ensure that they’re in compliance with our policies, and to monitor your apps accordingly to reduce the likelihood of future policy emails from us. Additionally, please note that our team reserves the right to disable accounts at any time if we continue to see violations occurring.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did you click the ads? or load/show interstitials ads in a loop?

Answer (score 1):

You click your own ads several times.  on purpose or not, you let other (users using same network) click your ads. 
For any reason, never click your own ads, that's the golden rule.  if you want to see and click your ads, you should use TEST DEVICE ID. 
see this link [Testing that admob working before publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991254/testing-that-admob-working-before-publish)

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link
[supprt.google.com](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/2753860?hl=en)

in that see Invalid clicks and impressions
you got your answer why your account will be disable