# AdMob with no internet connection

Tags: android, admob, cocos2d-x, ads

How can I use AdMob in android if I cannot connect to internet? Is there any way of simulating a google service on own my laptop so I can test my application even if I cannot connect to internet?

Comment: Luis still got some doubts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can show an admob on the device if you don't have an internet connection, how you will guarantee that the add get viewed the number of times the app say.

So im gonna say (sadly) the answer its NOT.

Now if you don't want to break the app when there is not internet connection you can show a custom imagen follow [this tutorial](http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.mx/2012/06/show-custom-image-when-no-admob-ad-is.html) for more information

> Is there any way of simulating a google service

Wich one? there is a lot

Comment: You can try with a proxy

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991254/testing-that-admob-working-before-publish)

Comment: Some countries are not allowed to use some Google Ads Services. It means that developers from those countries can not be sure if an app with Ads works as expected until the app  will be tested outside the country. 
An alternative for testing the app without access to Google Ads Service is to simulate the service, so the developer will be able to test the app. The question is, where can I find such simulator?

Comment: Ethaan, I think that it is exactly what I need. I will try it and I will let you know my experiences.